# Code for device magnetic heading not working iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift, heading

I have the following swift code: It is meant to find the current magnetic heading of the device (i.e. N, E, S, W)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController ,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var lm:CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        lm = CLLocationManager()
        lm.delegate = self

        lm.startUpdatingHeading()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading!) {
        println(newHeading.magneticHeading)
    }
}
```

It seems like it should work but it doesn't. Can anybody improve on it?

Comment: You need to ask the user if you can use location services first. `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()`

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to add the following lines to your info.plist:

Either

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

or

```
<key> NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

depending on what you really needs for the app.

Both keys are described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW27).

And then, you should ask the user for authorization, as sbarow already pointed out in the comments to your question, via

```
lm.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```